# use doskey to replace part of command

Tags: batch-file, cmd, alias, doskey

I want to run doskey macros one after other. Since

```
doskey a = "some big command"
doskey b = "other big command"
..
..
```

and `a && b`
does not work, I do

```
for /l %i in (1 1 1) do (
a
b
...)
```

I want to replace this using a small command like `run (a b c d)` or

```
run (
a
b
)
```

How do I do it? `doskey run = for /l %i in (1 1 1) do` does not work.

Comment: You cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file.

Comment: What about `a & b`?

Comment: @Squashman I donot want to run from macros from a batch file. I already have a set of doskey macros which are quite long and take around 30 mins each. From command line I want to call them sequentially before I go out for a coffee, so that they are done by the time I come back.

Comment: @aschipfl `a & b`doesn't work. Only a executes saying b is not recognizable command.